# How to use get keyboard input using Mac? (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I want to try and get a keyboard input and use it in a conditional statement; such as if 'a' is pressed do function, if 'b' is pressed do function b. The problem is, whenever I get keyboard output, this error gets displayed. raise OSError("Error 13 - Must be run as administrator")
OSError: Error 13 - Must be run as administrator. I looked at some other posts, but I couldn't find a working solution. [Btw I am using the keyboard module (But it makes the error pop up), If there are any better solutions please tell].
Il put a code example I found:

```
    import keyboard  
    keyboard.write("GEEKS FOR GEEKS\n")  
    keyboard.press_and_release('shift + r, shift + k, \n') 
    keyboard.press_and_release('R, K') 
    keyboard.wait('Ctrl')
```

Note: I don't know how to get it to run, also if there is any problems in it, please tell a viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Must be run as admin, please elevate your privileges in that console with sudo

Comment: Im a bit of a noobie, but can you tell me the sudo command?

Comment: mmm, not much, because I'd like you to step up the effort you are willing to put into researching solutions to your problems. Elevating privileges, or running sudo in a terminal on Linux or MacOS (they share a common ancestry as operative systems) is the same as saying having root permissions or root user. On Windows, is equivalent of running as administrator. A quick search on the internet would have brought you [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012). Keep it up with Python